# How do I find the decryption algorithm and key using a encrypted version of a file and a decrypted version of a file

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, file-encryption, file-format

How do I find decryption algorithm and key using a encrypted version of a file and a decrypted version of a file? I have 4 files, 2 encrypted and 2 decrypted, I think the contents are the same if the encrypted one would be decrypted, I'm a noob at this and don't know what to do, so can someone do this for me or help me. Here is the file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/b6q3rsl635xwddc/encryption.rar/file

Comment: To identify the algorithm, the best approach is probably to open the encrypted files in a hex editor (e.g., [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) on Windows) and look for the [magic bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) at the start of the file. This may give an indication of the program that was used and hence the algorithm that program uses. However, there may be support for multiple algorithms or the files may appear completely random/have no magic bytes. If you can find information on the file headers/algorithm padding, the size difference may suggest the files match.